# Active Record Query returns Object Doesn't Support #inspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following query

```
User.where('name LIKE ?', "%Jason%").select("name")
```

However, when I run it in console I'm returned with this error

```
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do your relationships look like?

Comment: Fairly Complex. I'm confused at how the relationships will have anything to do with the query though since I'm only referencing one table and selecting a field from that same table. Care to explain your logic?

Comment: i wonder if you comment on all your associations the problem will still appear?

Comment: @fmendez Silly mistake on my part. Post your comment as the answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks.

Comment: @jason328 I actually deleted the comment because I tried this in a project an it worked: `User.where("email LIKE ?", "%mendez%").select("updated_at")`. Im not sure if it has to do with the rails version. Perhaps the lasted one do support `select` on relation.

Comment: @fmendez I'm using 3.2.12 but your comment still helped me. I ran a simple loop and pushed to an array. Maybe note in your answer the differences between your version and mine.

Comment: The code looks fine as is, can you post a stacktrace?